# Loops in category description

Tags: categories, loop, tags, description

I would like your help to find how to do a thing I need:

I have some posts,  for example:

- Article Title: Banana
- Article Title: Orange
- Article Title: Lemon
- Article Title: Strawberry

All this articles need to have breadcrumb like this: Home > Fruits > #Title#

In the "Fruits" category page I would like to create something like this:

## Yellow Fruits

(and a list of all articles about fruits that are yellow)

## Orange Fruits

(and a list of all articles about fruits that are orange)

## Red Fruits

(and a list of all articles about fruits that are red)

To do this, I think in the description of category I should write manually the titles (Yellow Fruits, Orange Fruits, Red Fruits), and under each title I should put a loop to put all articles that have a specific tag (for example to the article called "Banana" I will give a tag "yellow").

Do you think it can work? do you have other ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to *group* fruits by color. In WordPress term appropriate mechanism for that is taxonomy (categories and tags are examples of taxonomy).

I would create a custom taxonomy "fruit color" where terms would be individual colors and assigned to fruits.

Then your display logic would be to:

- retrieve all fruit colors terms
- for each term display its title and posts that have the term assigned

You *could* do this with tags (since tags *are* taxonomy), but it works cleaner when taxonomies have specific purpose and don't mean different things in different contexts (as in your tag would mean "color" for fruits, but something entirely different for non-fruits).